# Meteor MUP Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

Have tried reinstalling mup and changing versions of node. Can't figure out how to fix this error. Believe it may be caused by the settings file or bcrypt, but at a loss for what to do to fix the issue.

```
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.Npm.require (/opt/production/app/programs/server/boot.js:182:18)
    at Package (packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1)
    at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1
    at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #96
[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] /opt/production/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236] throw(ex);[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236] ^[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] Error: /opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at require (module.js:380:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at bindings (/opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at require (module.js:380:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.Npm.require (/opt/production/app/programs/server/boot.js:182:18)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Package (packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] error: Script restart attempt #97[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] /opt/production/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236] throw(ex);[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]    [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236]  [107.170.31.236] ^[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] Error: /opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at require (module.js:380:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at bindings (/opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/production/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at require (module.js:380:17)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Object.Npm.require (/opt/production/app/programs/server/boot.js:182:18)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at Package (packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1)[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236]     at packages/npm-bcrypt/wrapper.js:1:1[107.170.31.236]
[107.170.31.236] error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8[107.170.31.236]
```

Comment: are your development machine and your target (production) machine running the same OS? I suspect not and that bcrypt has some native code that needs to be compiled on the target architecture. If that is the case, you may not be able to use mup for this. The new mupx should work tough.

Comment: actually I'm getting similar problem. I just changed port to 3000 and used nginx as proxy